# Wicket 6 and on the fly javascript compression

Tags: wicket

I know that wicket will take min files when running in deployment mode. But I would like to have possibility to bundle multiple javascript files into one, so that the generated page can load whole javascript from single url. This should happen only is deployment mode, development should still deliver pages containing multiple javascript files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "resource bundles". See http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/resources.html#resources_6.
You can wrap the registrations with "if (usesDeploymentMode()) {...}"